# Java 2D array with random number Symetric matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am trying to make a method which creates a 2D symetrix matrix that is generated randomly and it is of n size. The random numbers also have to be between 0 and 100.

Heres what i got so far;

```
public static void randomArray(int n)
{
         Random random = new Random();

            double[][] array = new double[n][n];

            for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) { 
               for ( int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length ; j++ ) { 
                  array[i][j] = random.nextInt(101);
               }
            }
            for( double[] a : array ) { 
                System.out.println( Arrays.toString( a ));
            }

    }//end of randomArray
```

This successfully generates a 2D array with random numbers, but the matrix is not symetric and i am confused as to how to make it symetrix.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what your problem is?  If you want the values in the bottom to match the top, use the values from the top instead of picking new random values.  What is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: how do you want the matrix to be symmetric? or describe your definition of symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the random value that you assigned to `array[i][j]`, you also assign it to `array[j][i]`, except for the matrix diagonal of course.

Also, you change your inner loop stopping condition to be `j<=i`, so you don't iterate over the other side of the matrix.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    int x = random.nextInt(101);
    array[i][j] = x;
    if (i != j) {
      array[j][i] = x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't actually matter if `i==j`. The assignment is idempotent.

Comment: You are correct, i just added it to avoid the double assignment for the diagonal values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution. I assume from your description that 2D matrix is to represent a graph.

```
public static double[][] RandomArray(int n){
        
        double [][] array = new double[n][n];
        

        Random rand = new Random();
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
                Integer r = Math.abs(rand.nextInt(101));
                array[i][j] = r;
                if (i != j) {
                    array[j][i] = r;
                }
                else {
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return array;
        
    }
```